# How to inject one module to another in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module

I have 2 module within the same namespace.

`MyCompany/Module1/` and `MyCompany/Module2/`

Now, I want to call some function of `MyCompany/Module1/` from `MyCompany/Module2/`

If I add module1 in the constructor of module2 it didn't work.

How to inject it?

Comment: can you should some code?

Comment: Actually my  module 2 will perform some http request to some external api. And I need to the result in module 2.
Do I really need controller or model for this?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use **model** for that because model are reusable and you can call anywhere or use **helper**.
You can use model with below code..

```
protected $_moduleloader;  


  public function __construct(
        .....
        \MyCompany\Module1\Model\ModelFactory $_moduleloader
        .....

    ) {

        ...........
        $this->_moduleloader = $_moduleloader;
       ..........
    }
    public function getdataModule()
    {
        return $this->_moduleloader->someMethod();
    }
```